# Cakephp 2 virtual field not function

Tags: cakephp

I have problem with virtual field, can you help me?

My model UserAddress

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $virtualFields = array('users_list' => 'concat(User.name, " - ", User.surname, " - ", User.email)');
```

My controller UserAddressesController:

```
$users = $this->User->find('list', array('list',array('fields' => array("id","users_list"))));
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

My view UserAddresses/edit:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('users_id', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

Report notice:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: users_list [APP/Plugin/User/Controller/UserAddressesController.php, line 94]
>   Code Context
>   array('fields' => array("id","users_list"))));

Comment: What exactly is on line 94 of your controller? Also, the find call doesn't need the `'list'` value in the options array. It should just be `$this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array(...`

Comment: this is line 94.      $users = $this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array("id","users_list")));  thanks a lot, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution from the comment above:

The find call doesn't need the `'list'` value in the options array. It should just be `$this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array(...`